# Why this plot of Siegel Z function is very close to two halve lines?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $Z(s)$ be Siegel $Z$ function.
For real $S,T$, define $fu7(S,T)=|Z((S-\frac12)/i + T)|$.

In other words for $s=S + i T$ we have $fu7(s)=|Z((s-\frac12)/i)|$.

For $S_0 \in (0,1)$ and $T_0=\rho_1= 14.1...$ the imaginary part
of the first zeta zero, $fu7(S_0,T_0)$ is very close to two halve
lines intersecting at the zero.

The numeric derivative of $fu7(S0,T0)$ is also close to constant.

How to interpret this, could the plot be dominated by the zero,
missing some additional correction?

Sagemath code, you can run it in a [browser](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFz1ELgjAQB_B3we8wQnBHy-ZDBIWfoh4FsXZLYzo5F4mfvmUW9dSe_rttv7vVTWfJsaZrSleFwVFmr5jUDZ_TiK4ckSxPAcJAoWb6tlVIfIAdY4TuRu0MJKrWmvtjMQD7tz7WBIXBVPzldHnq32P0NV7QjJzzYSWTDazn-nXJjhIYgCc6s806Y91zBCakSMXZGktZfCHENhbGE60qTHlCky2iZ-9DIUWeU2WLFKIF7D0xOf6DH8rnb4xQxTBdSvrK3jm8H8zbByMBZOU=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

sage:
[image]
[image]

```
import mpmath
T0=mpmath.im(mpmath.zetazero(1))
def fu7der(x):  return mpmath.diff(fu7,x)                                 
def fu7(x): 
     return mpmath.fabs(mpmath.siegelz(((x-0.5)/mpmath.j+ T0) )) 
pl7=plot(fu7 ,0,1,color='green',legend_label="$fu7(S_0,\\rho_1)$");pl7
```

Comment: Neglecting the absolute value, Mathematica can give a series expansion around $S_0=1/2$.  The constant term is of course zero, but the quadratic and higher coefficients are surprisingly small:$-0.79316 i \left(S_0-1/2\right)-0.0651646 \left(S_0-1/2\right)^2-0.0207078 i
   \left(S_0-1/2\right)^3-0.00317298 \left(S_0-1/2\right)^4+O\left(S_0-1/2\right)^5$

Comment: Of course, Mathematica can give the coefficients in closed form, but they are complicated and I don't see why the quadratic and higher coefficients are small.